# No touch event for li tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, touch

I use **touch monitor** and **html page** (MS Windows 7 Pro Eng, IE8). And I discovered that touch fires when text area of `li` tag is tapped and the rest is ignored.

[image]

How change it so even if user tap on white/non-text area of the li it fires as it should.

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<ul class="nav" id="mainList">
        <li class="touchedLi stripe-even" id="item0"><a  href="#">Club Yellow 1</a></li>
        <li class="touchedLi stripe-odd" id="item1"><a href="#">Club Yellow 2</a></li>
        <li class="touchedLi stripe-even" id="item2"><a  href="#">Club Yellow 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li.stripe-even {
    background-color: #FFF1ED;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li.stripe-odd{
  background-color: #F2FFED;
  list-style-type:none;
}

ul.mainList li:hover{
background-color: yellow;
}

#mainList a:active {
    color: white;
    background-color: orange;
}

#mainList>li>a {
    display: block;
}
```

```css
li.stripe-even {
background-color: #FFF1ED;
list-style-type: none;
}

li.stripe-odd{
  background-color: #F2FFED;
  list-style-type:none;
}

 ul.mainList li:hover{
    background-color: yellow;
    }
    
    #mainList a:active {
     color: white;
        background-color: orange;
    }
    
    #mainList>li>a {
        display: block;
    }

    #mainList>li {
        display: block;
    }

 #mainList>li {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 


<ul class="nav" id="mainList">
            <li class="touchedLi stripe-even" id="item0"><a  href="#">Club Yellow 1</a></li>
            <li class="touchedLi stripe-odd" id="item1"><a href="#">Club Yellow 2</a></li>
            <li class="touchedLi stripe-even" id="item2"><a  href="#">Club Yellow 3</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: could you tell us as well wich browser and OS does not behave as expected, or is it all of them in any OS ?

Comment: @GCyrillus Please take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Dimi, create a [mcve] of your problem. Unless we see what CSS applies we cannot help. Use the sinppet/code tool here on SO or create a jsFiddle/codepen, etc...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Sure, please help me.

Comment: @GCyrillus Well... It does not work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found working solution

Nothing is working but only `&nbsp;`

So the `li` tag should look like this

```
<ul class="nav" id="mainList">
            <li class="touchedLi stripe-even" id="item0"><a  href="#">Club Yellow 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li class="touchedLi stripe-odd" id="item1"><a href="#">Club Yellow 2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li class="touchedLi stripe-even" id="item2"><a  href="#">Club Yellow 3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then the area of `&nbsp;` is a touchable area! :)

How you are gonna add `&nbsp;` it depends of your needs.

Answer (score -1):

What is your CSS? Try adding display: block to the a tag.